# Pandas: Better Way to Group By and Find Mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a spreadsheet of stock prices for all companies, and I'd like to calculate the moving average more efficiently. As it stands I have some code that works, but takes a pretty long time to run. I'm wondering what are alternative ways to do the same thing, but more efficiently, or in a way that utilizes Pandas' strengths.

Here is the workflow I am trying to accomplish in my code:

1. I first want to take the 20 day rolling/moving average for each company, and add it as a column to the dataframe (`sma_20`).
2. From there I want to count the number of days a stock's price was over this 20 day average.
3. Finally, I want to convert this count into a percentage. For reference, there are 252 days in a trading year, I'd like to see out of these 252 days, how many of them was the stock trading above it's moving average.

```py
prices_df['sma_20'] = prices_df.groupby('ticker').rolling(20)['closeadj'].mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)
prices_df['above_sma_20'] = np.where(prices_df.closeadj > prices_df.sma_20, 1, 0)
prices_df['above_sma_20_count'] = prices_df.groupby('ticker').rolling(252)['above_sma_20'].sum().reset_index(0,drop=True)
prices_df['above_sma_20_pct'] = prices_df['above_sma_20_count'] / 252
```

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rearrange the data into n(date) by m(ticker) array, and use `numpy` to deal with rolling mean,

Given a `df` with 100 companies and 253 days from yahoo finance,
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_n = df.to_numpy()
sma_20 = np.cumsum(df_n, dtype=float, axis=0)
sma_20[20:] = sma_20[20:] - sma_20[:-20]
sma_20[19:] = sma_20[19:] / 20
sma_20[:19] = sma_20[:19] / np.arange(1, 20)[:, None]
```

```
print(sum(df_n > sma_20)/len(df_n))
>>>
[0.41897233 0.61660079 0.7312253  0.71936759 0.74703557 0.743083
 0.52964427 0.53359684 0.52964427 0.45849802 0.64031621 0.63241107
 0.59683794 0.66798419 0.77470356 0.56521739 0.64426877 0.60869565
 0.46640316 0.45059289 0.61660079 0.743083   0.69565217 0.56916996
 0.63241107 0.69565217 0.55731225 0.6284585  0.60869565 0.66798419
 0.59683794 0.56126482 0.62055336 0.65612648 0.54150198 0.46245059
 0.62055336 0.54545455 0.54545455 0.68379447 0.59683794 0.50988142
 0.81422925 0.65217391 0.60869565 0.66798419 0.56126482 0.57312253
 0.74703557 0.64822134 0.44664032 0.67588933 0.6284585  0.61264822
 0.60474308 0.50197628 0.58498024 0.54545455 0.65612648 0.61660079
 0.66007905 0.64822134 0.60869565 0.58893281 0.68774704 0.66403162
 0.50988142 0.62055336 0.4743083  0.53754941 0.60869565 0.62055336
 0.60869565 0.743083   0.43873518 0.6916996  0.71936759 0.61264822
 0.59288538 0.49011858 0.58102767 0.5256917  0.59288538 0.45454545
 0.49407115 0.55335968 0.49011858 0.64031621 0.6798419  0.54150198
 0.59683794 0.67588933 0.56126482 0.60474308 0.45454545 0.61264822
 0.56521739 0.48221344 0.40711462 0.68379447]
```

Assign the probability and corresponding company to a new dataframe,

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame(sum(df_n > sma_20)/len(df_n), columns=['probability'])
df_result['company'] = df.columns
df_result = df_result.sort_values(by='probability', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
df_result
###
    probability company
0      0.814229    FTNT
1      0.774704    ASML
2      0.747036    INTU
3      0.747036   GOOGL
4      0.743083    AVGO
..          ...     ...
95     0.450593    BIIB
96     0.446640      JD
97     0.438735    PCAR
98     0.418972    ATVI
99     0.407115      ZM

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```